# Crosstab/Frequency/Count across multiple variables in R

Tags: r, count, frequency, crosstab

I hope I explain this easily, but my end goal is this: when 'Candidate' is say 'Donald Trump', among all Race(n) columns, what percentage of respondents were 'White'.  So in this case, there are 5 instances of 'Donald Trump' and 2 'White' observations from 'Race1' so 40% of those who chose 'Donald Trump' were 'White'.  And then find percentage totals for all other Race(n) columns and Gender columns. Absolutely cannot figure out the best method whether its using frequency, crosstabs, counts, etc.

I know I'm asking a lot by this second part, but in addition, when 'Candidate' is 'Donald Trump', what percentage of female respondents 'Gender1' were White Females or Black Females.

And as a big bonus, is there a good package for presenting the results?  Thanks you so so much for any help.

```
Candidate       Race1   Race2   Race3   Race4   Gender1   Gender2

Donald Trump    White                           Female
Democrat        White                                     Male        
Donald Trump            Black                   Female
Donald Trump                    Asian           Female
Democrat                        Asian                     Male
Democrat                Black                   Female
Democrat                                Latino            Male
Donald Trump                            Latino            Male
Donald Trump    White                           Female
```

Comment: Could you formulate your problem in one or two concise questions? Also it is important to share what you have already tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `library(dplyr)`, but here is what I am thinking:

```
data_f  <-  data %>% 
            cbind(Race = coalesce(!!!select(data, starts_with("Race"))), 
                  Gender = coalesce(!!!select(data,starts_with("Gender"))))
```

`coalesce` combines your columns that begin with `Race` and then with `Gender` into one column as the columns you provided are mutually exclusive.

```
data_r  <-  data_f %>%
            group_by(Candidate, Race) %>%
            summarise(Race_count = n()) %>%
            ungroup() %>%
            left_join(data_f %>% 
                        group_by(Candidate) %>%
                        summarise(Total_Race_Ct = n()), by = "Candidate") %>%
            mutate(Per_Race = Race_count/Total_Race_Ct)
```

This yields the following as a percent of total candidate-specific votes for a Race analysis:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 5
  Candidate    Race   Race_count Total_Race_Ct Per_Race
  <chr>        <fct>       <int>         <int>    <dbl>
1 Democrat     Asian           1             4     0.25
2 Democrat     Black           1             4     0.25
3 Democrat     Latino          1             4     0.25
4 Democrat     White           1             4     0.25
5 Donald Trump Asian           1             5     0.2 
6 Donald Trump Black           1             5     0.2 
7 Donald Trump Latino          1             5     0.2 
8 Donald Trump White           2             5     0.4
```

For gender analysis:

```
data_g  <-  data_f %>%
            group_by(Candidate, Gender) %>%
            summarise(Gender_count = n()) %>%
            ungroup() %>%
            left_join(data_f %>% 
                      group_by(Candidate) %>%
                      summarise(Total_Gender_Ct = n()), by = "Candidate") %>%
            mutate(Per_Gender = Gender_count/Total_Gender_Ct)
```

This yields the following as a percent of total candidate-specific votes for a Gender analysis:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  Candidate    Gender Gender_count Total_Gender_Ct Per_Gender
  <chr>        <fct>         <int>           <int>      <dbl>
1 Democrat     Female            1               4       0.25
2 Democrat     Male              3               4       0.75
3 Donald Trump Female            4               5       0.8 
4 Donald Trump Male              1               5       0.2
```

Comment: this is incredible!! thank you so much!  i should be paying you for this!

Answer (score 0):

Will have to do some cleaning first with `tidyr` to get each variable in 1 column and each observation in 1 row:

```
survey <- survey %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Race"),
                                  names_to = "xRace",
                                  values_to = 'Race')
survey <- survey %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Gender"),
                                  names_to = "xGender",
                                  values_to = "Gender")
clean_survey <- survey %>% select(-xRace, -xGender) %>% drop_na()
clean_survey
```

This will yield this tibble:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  Candidate    Race   Gender
  <chr>        <chr>  <chr> 
1 Donald Trump white  Female
2 Democrat     white  Male  
3 Donald Trump Black  Female
4 Donald Trump Asian  Female
5 Democrat     Asian  Male  
6 Democrat     Black  Female
7 Democrat     Latino Male  
8 Donald Trump Latino Male  
9 Donald Trump white  Female
```

Now it's ready to be investigated with `janitor` library for cross-tabulation

```
race_vs_candidate <- 
  tabyl(clean_survey, Race, Candidate,Gender) %>% 
  adorn_percentages("col") %>% 
  adorn_pct_formatting() %>% 
  adorn_ns()
race_vs_candidate
```

and this is the cross-tab Race vs candidate

```
> race_vs_candidate
Race  Democrat Donald Trump
  Asian 25.0% (1)    20.0% (1)
  Black 25.0% (1)    20.0% (1)
 Latino 25.0% (1)    20.0% (1)
  white 25.0% (1)    40.0% (2)
```

here we break down by gender

```
gender_race_candidate <- 
  tabyl(clean_survey, Race, Candidate,Gender) %>% 
  adorn_percentages("col") %>% 
  adorn_pct_formatting() %>% 
  adorn_ns()
gender_race_candidate
```

and the result:

```
> gender_race_candidate

$Female
   Race   Democrat Donald Trump
  Asian   0.0% (0)    25.0% (1)
  Black 100.0% (1)    25.0% (1)
 Latino   0.0% (0)     0.0% (0)
  white   0.0% (0)    50.0% (2)

$Male
   Race  Democrat Donald Trump
  Asian 33.3% (1)     0.0% (0)
  Black  0.0% (0)     0.0% (0)
 Latino 33.3% (1)   100.0% (1)
  white 33.3% (1)     0.0% (0)
```

Also we can get gender Vs race:

```
gender_race <- 
  tabyl(clean_survey,Gender, Race) %>% 
  adorn_percentages("col") %>% 
  adorn_pct_formatting() %>% 
  adorn_ns()
gender_race
```

outcome:

```
> gender_race
 Gender     Asian      Black     Latino     white
 Female 50.0% (1) 100.0% (2)   0.0% (0) 66.7% (2)
   Male 50.0% (1)   0.0% (0) 100.0% (2) 33.3% (1)
```

for gender Vs candidate, here it is with more details of `adorn_totals()`

```
gender_candidate <- 
  tabyl(clean_survey,Gender, Candidate) %>%
  adorn_totals() %>%
  adorn_percentages("col") %>% 
  adorn_pct_formatting() %>% 
  adorn_ns()
gender_candidate
```

the contingency table :

```
> gender_candidate
 Gender   Democrat Donald Trump
 Female  25.0% (1)    80.0% (4)
   Male  75.0% (3)    20.0% (1)
  Total 100.0% (4)   100.0% (5)
```

hope someone find this useful !